# Service interface - comparison of a couple of approaches

Tags: c#, .net, soa

I'm having a hard time deciding which approach is better:

```
interface IService {
  ISomething CreateSomething();
}

interface ISomething {
  void Do(string parameter);
}
```

vs

```
interface IService {
  ISomething CreateSomething();
  void DoSomething(ISomething something, string parameter);
}
```

vs

```
interface IService {
  ISomething CreateSomething();
  void DoSomething(int somethingId, string parameter)
}
```

vs

```
interface IService {
  int CreateSomething(); // returns something.Id
  void DoSomething(int somethingId, string parameter);
}
```

vs any other...

The `IService` interface is supposed to be consumed in a number of different ways:

- As a class library
- As a WCF Service
- As an XML Service
- As a JSON Service

`ISomething` may have a number of properties that the client will want to investigate, and a number of operations it may perform. `ISomething` is just one of dozen classes I need to expose this way. `ISomething` may return more interfaces that I can perform operations on.

I will appreciate any and suggestions and thoughts.

**EDIT:**

The idea is to create a service that will allow the users to build a workflow graph, and will support a designer. My requirements are to have service code that will support any flavor of a client (therefore the `int` parameter approaches). At the same time I don't want to run into an explosion of types and method.

Maybe the best approach would be to design it as a feature rich .NET library, and create facades (?) for any channels that may be consuming that?

Comment: Option #1 would seem the best to me. The "doing" of something seems to be an operation of the `ISomething`, not of the `IService`.

Comment: I don't think your question is realistically answerable by us; we don't know your requirements, business logic, etc.  The generic answer would be: do what works for you and fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
interface IService {
  ISomething CreateSomething();
  void DoSomething(int somethingId, string parameter)
}
```

imho it would generate least traffic since if you just return ID from `CreateSomething` you'll most likely do another trip if you need the details for processing.

Using the id in `DoSomething` gives you  the least traffic since the entire object doesn't seem to be necessary.

Always try to design service interfaces so that you have to use a few calls as possible to do what you want. That also means that it's difficult to tell you an answer since I do not know the intended purpose.

Comment: It is ugly if used in a class library. But I agree with everything else you say, so the question is are not requirements **too** generalized.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see is that you want for a class to be a service and data contract at the same time. `ISomething` can't be interface, because you actually pass concrete types and your clients should know their structure. So my suggestion is that service remains service and data contract remains itself.

```
class Something
{
}

interface IService {  
  void Do(string parameter);
  Something GetSomething();
}

class SomeService : IService {
  private Something smth;  

  public void SomeService()
  {
    smth = CreateSomething();
  }

  public void Do()
  {
    //
  }

  public Something GetSomething()
  {
    return smth;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as there may be more than just one instance of `ISomething` involved.